# Create a tensor based on counts on another tensor (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to sort a 1-D tensor such that the tensor is sorted based on the frequency of items in the tensor, for instance given this tensor [6,0,1,0,2,6,6], I want to sort it like this [6,6,6,0,0,1,2], so far I got this far:

```
ks = tf.constant([6,0,1,0,2,6,6])
unique_s, idx, cnts = tf.unique_with_counts(ks)
r = tf.gather(unique_s,tf.nn.top_k(cnts, k=(1+tf.reduce_max(idx))).indices)
s = tf.gather(cnts,tf.nn.top_k(cnts, k=(1+tf.reduce_max(idx))).indices)
```

in which r contains the values [6, 0, 1, 2] and s contains [3,2,1,1]. Now, I want to expand r based on the counts in s. So, in Python, we can make the above list like this:

```
sorted_arr = []
for i,_s in enumerate(s):
    sorted_arr.expand([r[i]]*_s)
```

but since iteration over a tensor is not allowed in tensorflow, I'm kinda stuck, right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure there is a more elegant solution, but here goes:

This requires running two sessions:

1. Find the number of unique values
2. Split, multiply & combine

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
ks = tf.constant([6,0,1,0,2,6,6])
unique_s, idx, cnts = tf.unique_with_counts(ks)
r = tf.gather(unique_s,tf.nn.top_k(cnts, k=(1+tf.reduce_max(idx))).indices)
# Dynamic length of r
len_r = tf.shape(r)
s = tf.gather(cnts,tf.nn.top_k(cnts, k=(1+tf.reduce_max(idx))).indices)

# Evaluate number of unique values
with tf.Session() as sess:
    splits = len_r.eval()[0]

# Split r & s into a list of tensors
split_r = tf.split(r, splits)
split_s = tf.split(s, splits)
# Tile r, s times
mult = [tf.tile(each_r,each_s) for each_r, each_s in zip(split_r, split_s)]
# Concatenate
join = tf.concat(mult, axis=0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(join.eval())
```

Output `[6 6 6 0 0 1 2]`